# Pearson chi-squared vs. logistic regression?

Tags: logistic, chi-squared-test

I have a dataset with calf serum BHB concentration expressed as low (<150) or high (>150). I want to know if there is a difference in BHB between age categories (weeks). I tested two analysis:

Pearson Chi-squared test. Here is the script with the results:

```r
t <- table(file$BHB_gr, file$stade3)
 
chisq.posthoc.test(t, method = "bonferroni")
 
pairwise_prop_test(t)
```

[image]

2. Logistic regression. Here is the script with the results:

```r
 bhb_m <- glm(as.factor(BHB_gr) ~ stade3, data=file, 
              family=binomial)
 
 summary(bhb_m)
 
 emm <- emmeans(bhb_m, "stade3")
 
 contrasts <- contrast(emm, method = "pairwise")
 
 summary(contrasts)
```

[image]

[image]

The issue is that I get very different results, but I cannot figure out why and which method is the most appropriate.

I also tested mixed effect logistic regression to control for the farm effect (farm as random effect) and the results were similar to the logistic regression.

Here is a plot of the data. We can clearly see no difference between the 3 first age categories (low BHB) and the last category stands out with high BHB.

[image]

Comment: Would you have numerical BHB data? If so, why using binary data cut at 150 rather than the full numerical information? Also, can you give information about sample size? The output of summary(bhb_m) may also be of interest.

Comment: I think it would also help to provide the rationale behind the age cuts here. They seem to be about every three years, but why? Unless there is a clinically defensible reason to do so, it may be better to make this data continuous, with which a logistic regression would be more appropriately suited for.

Comment: I have numerical data but they are left truncated (most of them are truncated). Also, in practice, we often use thresholds for BHB in calves (above 150 it means the rumen starts to function). That's why I used categories for BHB. Sample size is ~80 calves (15-20 per age category).

Comment: Age categories are in weeks. Data were collected for every age category so I need to keep them this way (these categories also make sense in the physiological development of calves).

Comment: I edited the post to add the results of summary(bhb_m).